# Java Array plus 1

Tags: java, arrays

my java code needs to plus 1 and im getting an error saying

```
ArrayTask3.java:8: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to int[]
     int[] row = intList [i];
```

It should just read my array and then add 1 to each number. could someone please help me get it to work correctly.

```
class ArrayTask3 {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int [] intList = {5,20,32,7,9};
      int sum = 0;

      for (int i = intList.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
         int[] row = intList [i];
         for (int j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
            row[j] = row[j] + 1;
         }

         System.out.println ("intList [" + i + "]: " + intList [i]);
      }
      for (int counter=0;counter<intList.length;counter++)
         sum = sum + intList[counter];
      System.out.println ("Sum = " + sum);
   }    
}
```

Comment: `intList` is an array of `int`(s). `intList[i]` is a single `int`. The value at index `i`. I think you wanted `intList[i]++;`

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hampster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`intList` is just a `int[]`, not a 2-d array. Instead of making a new array called "row" in your for loop, you can simply do `intList[i]++`.

(`intList[i]++` and `intList[i] = intList[i] + 1` and `intList[i] += 1` are the *same*)

```
for (int i = 0; i < intList.length; i++) {
    intList[i]++;
    System.out.println ("intList [" + i + "]: " + intList [i]);
}
```

Also, it's more normal to make your for loop be

```
for (int i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
    //code
}
```

instead of what you did, which is

```
for (int i = someArray.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    //code
}
```

Both of these do the exact same thing, but the first option is more "normal" and easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

The issue there was that you are setting an int array equal to an int ( not an array element equal to an int ). I fixed the code for you:

```
class ArrayTask3 {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
          int [] intList = {5,20,32,7,9};
          int sum = 0;

          for (int i = intList.length-1; i >=0; i--) {

            // you can directly set the element using this
            intList[i] = intList[i]+1;

             System.out.println ("intList [" + i + "]: " + intList [i]);
          }
          for (int counter=0;counter<intList.length;counter++)
             sum = sum + intList[counter];
          System.out.println ("Sum = " + sum);
       }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`intList` is a single dimensional array so `intList[i]` is the `int` at position `i` in `intList`. I think what you want to do is increase the integer by one or `intList[i]++;` or `intList[i] += 1;`.

You are currently trying to loop through a 2-dimensional array or matrix by selecting rows. In which case you would need to define `intList` as an `int[][]` or an array of integer arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
      for (int i = intList.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
         /**
          *  I am not sure on what you want to do with this line.
          *  You can't assign an integer to array without reference
          *  If you want to copy the value of intList to row you can use int[] row = intList;
          */
         int[] row = intList [i];

         for (int j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
           row[j] = row[j] + 1;
         }

        System.out.println ("intList [" + i + "]: " + intList [i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code. It adds 1 to each number and prints the sum of all numbers at the end.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] intList = { 5, 20, 32, 7, 9 };
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < intList.length; i++) {
    intList[i]++;
    System.out.println("intList [" + i + "]: " + intList[i]);
    sum += intList[i];
  }
  System.out.println(sum);
}
```